# Function that counts arbitrary function 1 to 10 in C

Tags: c, recursion, accumulator

How do I write a function that have a input function (is objective to any function), array of input numbers and length of input array?

Function:

```
double accumulator(double (*function)(double, double), double array[], int length)
```

Main:

```
int main(){
   double array[10];

   for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
      array[i] = i+1;

   printf("Sum is: %g\n", accumulator(sum,array,10));
   printf("Product is: %g\n", accumulator(product,array,10));

   return 0;
}
```

For example sum should be 55 (1 + 2 + .... + 10) and product 362880 (1 * 2 * ... * 10).
I guess the function should by recursive but I still cant get the right results :/

I have got this non-recursive solution but it of course works only for sum...

```
double accumulator(double (*function)(double, double), double array[], int length)
{
    int temp = 0;
    for (int i = 0;i<length;i++)
    {
        temp = (*function)(temp, array[i]);

    }
    return temp;
}
```

on the top of course:

```
double sum(double x, double y){
    return x+y;
}
double product(double x, double y){
    return x*y;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't work for multiplication because multiplying anything by `0` gives, well `0`

you need to use first element as an initial value

```
double accumulator(double (*function)(double, double), double array[], int length)
{
    int temp = array[0]; 
    for (int i = 1; i < length;i++) // start from #1
    {
        temp = (*function)(temp, array[i]);

    }
    return temp;
}
```

Comment: yep, it works! :) i thougth that would me more complicated, at the beginning i was close and i was missed only one line: `int temp = array[0];` :)

Answer (score 4):

What is wrong with:

```
double multiplicator(double (*function)(double, double), double array[], int length)
{
    int temp = 1;
    for (int i = 0;i<length;i++)
    {
        temp = (*function)(temp, array[i]);

    }
    return temp;
}
```

Either a different function or you need to supply the neutral element for the operation (0 for sum, 1 for product).

Comment: For the border case (empty array) you always need to supply a neutral element.

Answer (score 1):

Two thoughts:

1. You should use `double temp` rather than `int temp`.
2. You need to have a different starting value for addition versus multiplication. A sum should start at `temp = 0`, but a product should start at `temp = 1`. Otherwise the product will always be 0.

   You could add add another initial value parameter:

   ```
   double accumulator(double (*function)(double, double), double array[], int length, double initial)
   ```

   Or you use the first array element as the starting value (but then you'll need to check for the special case where the array is empty):

   ```
   double temp = array[0];
   ```

For what it's worth, your "accumulator" function is alternatively known as ["reduce"](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce) in [other](http://www.gnu.org/software/mit-scheme/documentation/mit-scheme-ref/Reduction-of-Lists.html) functional programming contexts. That may help if you want to Google the term.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is almost there if you set `temp = array[0]` and start your loop at `i = 1` instead of `i = 0`.